# Can I apply a wood veneer on stairs?

Tags: veneer, flooring

I have finished my pine stairs recently. I am not that happy with the end result as the wood colour doesn't match my floor (long story).

I am seeking solutions and friend suggested applying a an oak veneer (0.8mm). He is not exactly an expert, but if this worked it could actually be a good solution.
I am bit skeptical since stair are subject to a great wear.

Can I apply a veneer on stairs?

Comment: Just to mention something neither Answer has touched on, if you did want to go ahead with this plan bear in mind it requires the finish to be removed from the treads, which could be a really tricky thing. Plus you'd need to figure out some kind of nosing, to hide the pine at the leading edge of each tread. All in all I don't think this is viable.

Comment: @Graphus that's a good point, but right now the wood has nothing applied in it.

Comment: But I thought you said you'd stained them in your other Q. Along with the word "finished" here I took to mean they'd had finished applied.

Comment: I might suggest opening a new question here about fixing the staining. You might have better success with that than you would with veneering the stairs. Of course, before doing that, search through the existing questions tagged [tag:finishing] and [tag:refinishing].

Answer (score 4):

Veneers are very common on premade stair treads, but the question is could you apply a veneer on installed treads yourself and get similar results? It sounds like you have installed the treads and risers already.

Veneers will wear like any wood, but the difference in factory treads is that they have applied the veneer with the right heat, humidity, and pressure necessary to get that perfect bond to the substrate. And then topped it off with a high-wear finish.

Also, the veneers used in *good* engineered treads tend to be much thicker than <1mm, and could be refinished if you were careful. However, there is an upper limit to the thickness of veneer a home-gamer can apply with the usual tools available to them.

Engineered products also use a very hard and stable substrate, not plain old softwood.

You'd have a heck of a time getting good results (look good, no seams or bubbles, good adherence to the substrate) with the treads and risers already installed.

That being said, you could probably get away with it if the stairs weren't installed yet, and you were able to come up with a clamping or weighting solution to turn some cheap substrate lumber into veneered panels ready for turning into treads and risers.

(As pointed out by others, how you would trim, protect, and hide the veneer edges is left as an exercise for the reader; it would not be easy, and would add significantly to the workload. Again, this is something that factories with the right tooling can do in a minute that would take a carpenter literally days and not get the same results.)

You'd have to sweat these details, though, because an edge of lifting veneer or loose trim is the *perfect* way to trip people on stairs, and stairs are already a top killer in the home. Things are better than the terrible "servant" stairs the Victorians had in their houses (and much copied here in the colonies) but stairs are surprisingly tricky to **not** accidentally make into killing machines.

And, yes. It'll wear through eventually and then the whole tread will probably need to be replaced. Remember that part of DIY carpentry is not giving yourself *too* much repair and maintenance work. Your future self is busy enough as it is.

That *all* being said, you've given yourself a future of maintenance by using pine for the hard-wearing parts of stairs. They will wear fast, regardless of the finish you choose. So you will be refinishing them regularly, and they will never outlast their engineered counterparts. If I could go back in time and give you some advice, it would be to spend the money on hardwood for the treads, and use the pine for other parts that aren't directly stepped on.

Comment: +1. You might want to add in a mention about the difference in typical thickness in the surface layer of engineered floor products and modern veneers. Some of the flooring has a top layer thick enough I don't think it's accurately call it veneer any more, since they're well in excess of 1/16". One or two I've viewed here it seemed to be in excess of 5mm, so roughly 1/4".

Comment: You aren't wrong. Industry peels logs for a variety of applications, and treads tend to be the thicker of those.

Comment: "an edge of lifting veneer or loose trim is the _perfect_ way to trip people on stairs" _is_ important enough to have said it twice!

Comment: Oops. Copy and paste and undo and paste issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you think 'covering' the stairs is the best way to 'fix' the problem, I would go with a thicker laminate.  something like 1/8-1/4"  (3-6mm)  This would be thick enough to handle a lot of wear, and would be much easier to attach to the current stairs.  And still thin enough not to affect stair height much.  You could use glue and/or small finishing nails to secure them and you don't have to worry about bubbles, folds misalignment, tearing etc.

Comment: The issue to that is to do the bendings in the step. But you have a good point.